# Authentication of Azure using azure java sdk

Tags: azure, azure-authentication, azure-java-sdk

Is this the correct way of checking client, tenant,secret key are valid?
then what are the jars required to this code and where to download it?

```
String client = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
String tenant = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
String key = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
String subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(client, tenant,key, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
Azure azure = Azure.configure().authenticate(credentials).withDefaultSubscription();
azure.subscriptions().list();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get access token, you could try the [code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-daemon/blob/master/msal-client-credential-secret/src/main/java/ClientCredentialGrant.java#L45) below.

```
private static IAuthenticationResult getAccessTokenByClientCredentialGrant() throws Exception {

        ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                CONFIDENTIAL_CLIENT_ID,
                ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(CONFIDENTIAL_CLIENT_SECRET))
                .authority(TENANT_SPECIFIC_AUTHORITY)
                .build();

        // With client credentials flows the scope is ALWAYS of the shape "resource/.default", as the
        // application permissions need to be set statically (in the portal), and then granted by a tenant administrator
        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
                Collections.singleton(GRAPH_DEFAULT_SCOPE))
                .build();

        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
        return future.get();
    }
```

The dependency in the pom.xml like this, or dowanload the jar [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

For more details, see the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-daemon).

---

401 error is related to your permission. [Get subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/get) need scope `https://management.azure.com/.default`.

Comment: I tried this but getting many errors - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-daemon/blob/master/src/main/java/ClientCredentialGrant.java#L18

Comment: Thank you,I resolved errors. But by using access token received from above code unable to get Subscriptions , I am getting 401 error bu access code from this rest API "https://login.microsoftonline.com"+"/"+tenantid+"/oauth2/token  are using to get subscriptions.
Is there any changes required?