# Java Azure SDK, Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable failed

Tags: java, azure, authentication, ssl

I'm running some automation tests, using azure SDK.
It works fine at first,
after a couple of tries to authenticate(each test performs new authentication), getting the below error.
What could be the reason?

[image]

```
08:39:45 [jsystem] [pool-54-thread-1] INFO com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationAuthority - [Correlation ID: 5ceb4f83-441b-4263-8134-b91a69101b2d] Instance discovery was successful 
08:39:46 [jsystem] [pool-54-thread-1] ERROR com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - [Correlation ID: 5ceb4f83-441b-4263-8134-b91a69101b2d] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable failed. 
08:39:46 [jsystem] javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate ECDH keypair 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.configureHeaderAndExecuteOAuthCall(AdalOAuthRequest.java:145) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalOAuthRequest.send(AdalOAuthRequest.java:83) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalTokenRequest.executeOAuthRequestAndProcessResponse(AdalTokenRequest.java:87) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenCommon(AuthenticationContext.java:930) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:70) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AcquireTokenCallable.execute(AcquireTokenCallable.java:38) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AdalCallable.call(AdalCallable.java:47) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate ECDH keypair 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.ECDHKeyExchange$ECDHEPossession.(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.ECDHClientKeyExchange$ECDHEClientKeyExchangeProducer.produce(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.ClientKeyExchange$ClientKeyExchangeProducer.produce(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.ServerHelloDone$ServerHelloDoneConsumer.consume(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source) 
08:39:46 [jsystem] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Test with your code like this, and it works well. Please try to check the parameters in the code, and [test them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) in Postman.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.AzureEnvironment;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure;    
import com.microsoft.rest.LogLevel;

......

String CLIENT_ID = "application-id";
String CLIENT_SECRET = "client-secret";
String TENANT = "tenant-id";
String Subscription_id = "subscription-id";

ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(CLIENT_ID, TENANT, CLIENT_SECRET,
        AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        
try {   
    Azure azure = Azure.configure().withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE).authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(Subscription_id);
    System.out.println(azure.tenantId());    
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-client-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-client-authentication</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
        <version>1.39.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Another [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62441628/13308381) to authenticate and get access token.

---

There is an error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate ECDH keypair" in your issue. Please refer to [here](https://github.com/flathub/org.freedesktop.Sdk.Extension.openjdk11/issues/2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, changed the description of my problem so it will be more understandable

Comment: Could you share when you got the error? What's the difference with others?

Comment: Got the error while trying to authenticate, there is no difference with other tests, running the same azure authentication each time. maybe there is some limitation?